# multiple errors in renaming a group of variables and concatenating a suffix

Tags: stata

I'm spending a lot of time doing something that should be pretty simple.  I'm trying to change a group of variables to have the same name but with a different letter on the end.  I'm not understanding how arrays work or something: probably multiple things are wrong with my syntax, as I'm very unfamiliar with Stata.  I've been Googling for hours and can't figure this out and need to get away from the computer for a while.

```
local letters `" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z" "'
local i 1
local swap " "

foreach var of varlist q5_a-q5_o {
    local letter : word `i' of `letters' //select the 1st value in the array which is 'a'
    replace `swap' = "aspects" + "_" + `letter' //change swap to read 'aspects_a' 
    rename `var' `swap' //rename 'q5_a' to 'aspects_a'
    local `i' = `i' + 1 //add one to 'i' so that the next loop will change 'q5_b' to 'aspects_b'
}
```

Comment: General comment: Googling can be very indirect. You want to rename variables. Everything you need is in or near the Stata help for `rename`.  Googling here is like walking to the library to browse when what you want is in a book you already have.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I have experience with several other programming languages, but my approach for finding solutions in C++ is obviously not going to work for Stata.  I think I need to find some time to read through the Stata help, the syntax here is different enough that "figuring it out as I go" is proving time wasting and frustrating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Dimitriy V. Masterov points out, `rename` (in Stata 12 up) is capable of multiple renamings.

Indeed,

```
renpfix q5 aspect
```

would seem to be what you wanted.

The rest of this answer focuses on what was wrong with your approach. In your case, the first time you call up

```
replace `swap' =
```

local macro `swap` is just spaces, so Stata sees

```
replace =
```

which is illegal. But the whole idea of using `replace` is wrong here. It is not how to change local macros at all. In short, you are misreading `replace` as a way to manipulate strings. It is a way to change the contents of variables.

```
local letters `c(alpha)' 
local i = 1

foreach var of varlist q5_a-q5_o {
    local letter : word `i' of `letters' 
    rename `var' aspects_`letter' 
    local i = `i' + 1 
}
```

should work. Here we are exploiting the fact that the lower case letters "a" to "z" are already in `c(alpha)`: see towards the end of the output of `creturn list` for other useful bits and pieces. This could be made shorter:

```
local letters `c(alpha)' 
local i = 1

foreach var of varlist q5_a-q5_o {
    local letter : word `i++' of `letters' 
    rename `var' aspects_`letter' 
}
```

and shorter still:

```
local i = 1

foreach var of varlist q5_a-q5_o {
    local letter : word `i++' of `c(alpha)' 
    rename `var' aspects_`letter' 
}
```

and shorter still

```
foreach letter in `c(alpha)' { 
     rename q5_`letter' aspect_`letter' 
}
```

although as implied earlier this is what `renpfix` does for you any way.

Comment: Great!  Thank you so much, I'm learning Stata on the go for a research project for a class, I knew there had to be an easier way than renaming each variable one at a time.  Your answer is great, and I'll be able to use this for renaming lots of other variables too, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try group rename: `rename q5* aspects*`. If that's not what you want, give an example of some current variable names and their desired new names.